# Backward compatibility issues while DumpSaving Interpolation polynomials

Tags: differential-equations, data-format, compatibility

I have bkwrd compatibility issues when I save my NDSolve result (which is an interpolating polynomia) using `DumpSave` from Mathematica 8 on Windows 7 and then try loading it using Mathematica 7 on Linux.

Is there any way I could specify backward compatibility (and cross compatibility: files can be imported into different OS with or without the same version of mathematica) in `DumpSave`?

I have read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6689/204) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7490/204) but they don't address the same issue.

Also, is there anyway the interpolating functions can be saved in a human readable format?

[Example code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5959/204) to work on, for convenience.

Comment: Compatibility in `DumpSave`? As I recall, it is to be used only with your machine. See the docs: _"Files written by DumpSave can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written."_

Comment: Depending on the equation you solve with `NDSolve` the functionality needed to make the interpolation function may not exist in older versions. To look at it in human readable form you could use `InterpolationFunction[..]//InputForm` perhaps that helps.

Comment: @ruebenko Useful! Thanks!

Comment: @ruebenko The `//InputForm` takes forever to crank though.. at least on my 2GB RAM Linux machine running Mathematica 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [MX](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MX.html) format (that is written by `DumpSave`) is not portable between different computer systems.  One can't count on it being compatible either between versions, different OSs or different architectures (32 vs 64 bit).

I recommend that you use `Compress` and export the results as a string instead, [as I described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1960/12).  This is not as fast as saving to MX, but it has quite good performance, and [good compatibility](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/is-compress-compatible-between-different-mathematica-versions). (Note though that previous versions may not be able to handle certain data structures, e.g. `Graph`, even if they can load the file!)

Also, a warning: if you are saving interpolating functions, be sure to read about [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3293/12)!

Comment: Will try your approach of compressing and exporting as a string.

Comment: In `Export["data.mmaz", Compress[expression], "String"]
expression = Uncompress@Import["data.mmaz", "String"]
`, what is `expression`? The expression that has the interpolating polynomial assigne to it?

Comment: @DNA Both MX and this `Compress` trick are ways to save arbitrary Mathematica expressions.  `WDX` or `Package` would have worked too as `Export` formats, but they're much slower to import/exports.

Comment: @DNA The expression that you want to export, in this case the interpolating polynomial.  This kind of exporting is analogous to `Export`, not `DumpSave`.  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/12) to understand the difference.