# Export Mathematica interpolating function to other programming language (C++)

Tags: export, interpolation

I have an interpolating function in Mathematica from solving a complicated differential equation. I want to then use the interpolating function directly in my other program, which is written in C++. Is there any possible way to export the interpolating function over?

My first solution was to just export a table of values of the interpolating function, and then re-interpolate it in C++, but that seems very slow and roundabout, especially because I will have to do this multiple times.

Comment: Answers to [How to make use of an interpolating function outside of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37792/27951) and [Interpreting the interpolating function and saving data to plot with external program](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9645/27951) show how to extract either the piecewise polynomials, or the grid and numerical data, depending on what you want to do with your results afterwards. Also look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264911/27951) for a method to extract values straight from `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: Also related: [What's inside InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337/27951).